# Getting a Java SecurityException while starting an activity

Tags: java, android, exception, android-permissions

I am facing this weird situation where I am getting the below logs.

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

To resolve this, I have tried cleaning the project and adding the below permission however its not resolving the issue.

> android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Comment: posting only your error ain't gonna help. Also post your code and explain what you want to acheive

Comment: I am just starting an activity 

              try {
                        startActivity(showPaymentIntent);

                    }catch (Exception e){
                        
                    }

Comment: are you using run time permissions??

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. In this case, this would include the complete Java stack trace, the code involved in that stack trace, and the manifest entry for the activity that you are trying to start (assuming that it is your own activity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer: android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL is a signature level permission. Your app will not be able to use it until and unless it has the same signature as the system.

Which is not something you can achieve unless you either are the creator or the system build, or collaborating with them such that they are willing to sign your apk with their certificate. In other words, this is off limits for most developers.